# android listview video thumbnail scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview

I have listview with three viewholders one for image one for video one for audio 
In videholder i have listview in which I am showing thumbnail of video if it downloaded.Its working fine but when i scroll then that thumbnail set on another imageview too.

```
    mConvertView = convertView;
        chatMessage=chatMessages.get(position);

        final TextViewHolder mTextViewHolder;
        final ImageViewHolder mImageViewHolder;
        final AudioViewHolder mAudioViewHolder;

         Object object=chatMessages.get(position);
//      mHandler = new Handler();
        disply = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(disply).build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

        rd = new RecordBaseHandler(context);



    if(chatMessage.getAssetsId() != null)
      {

          if(chatMessage.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("audio"))

          {

              Log.d("Node", "Item position is "+chatMessages.get(position));

            mAudioViewHolder = getAudioViewHolder(mConvertView);
            mAudioViewHolder.mChatmessage=chatMessage;

            // TODO change below code
            if(chatMessage.getSenderId() != null)
                setAlignment(mAudioViewHolder, chatMessage.getSenderId().intValue() != ((SMBChatApp) context.getApplication()).getQbUser().getId().intValue());
            else
                setAlignment(mAudioViewHolder, false);


            mAudioViewHolder.play.setTag(position);

            mAudioViewHolder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage.getDate_sent()));

            mycontent = chatMessage.getProperty("content-type");

            try {
                Cursor rs = rd.getData(chatMessage.getAssetsId());
                rs.moveToFirst();

                filepath = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("file_path"));

                Log.d("Node", "FINALLY FILE PATH IS " + filepath);

                if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                    rs.close();
                }


                if (filepath != null) {

                    mAudioViewHolder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                } else {
                    mAudioViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mAudioViewHolder.download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("Node", "EXECPTIOn " + e);
            }


              mAudioViewHolder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("Node: ", "Reading all contacts..");
                    List<RecordModel> contacts = rd.getAllContacts();

                    for (RecordModel cn : contacts) {

                        String log = "Id: "+ cn.getId()+ " ,Name: "+ cn.getAttch_id()+ " ,Phone: " + cn.getFile_path();

                        Log.d("Node: ",log);

                    }



                    // File tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("record", ".mp3", f);

                    new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run() {
                            File tempMp3 = null;
                            try {
                                tempMp3 = File.createTempFile("record", ".mp3",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            //We are creating  folder first using mkdir 
                            File f =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/smbchat/");                         
                            if(!f.exists()){
                                f.mkdirs();
                            }

                            //then we want to store downloded file in that folder 
                            File output =  new File(f, "smb_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_audio.mp3");

                            Log.d("Node", "URL VALUE "+chatMessage.getUrl());
                            HttpRequest.get(chatMessage.getUrl()).receive(output);

                            audioFileName=String.valueOf(output);


                            Log.d("Node", "FILE SAVED SUCCESSFULLY"+tempMp3);
                            Log.d("Node", "FILE SAVED SUCCESSFULLY AUDIOFILENAME " + audioFileName);
                            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "file downloaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    mAudioViewHolder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            });



                            rd.addContact(new RecordModel(chatMessage.getAssetsId(), audioFileName));

                        };

                    }.start();

                }
            });








            mAudioViewHolder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {


                    mAudioViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mAudioViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    Log.d("DATA", "currently playing " + position);
                    playingAudioPosition = position;


                    Object tag = mAudioViewHolder.play.getTag();

                    // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.



                    String str=chatMessage.getAssetsId();

                    Cursor rs = rd.getData(str);
                    rs.moveToFirst();
                    try
                    {
                        filepath = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("file_path"));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mConvertView.getContext(), "File is not downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    Log.d("Node", "file path for id "+  str  + "is "+ filepath);

                    if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if(filepath==null) //we check whether file is present or not 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(mConvertView.getContext(), "File is Not downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        ((View)v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.btndn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //                                      mAudioViewHolder.download.setVisibility(mConvertView.VISIBLE);
                    }
               else {
                                ((View) v.getParent()).findViewById(
                                        R.id.chat_audio_progress_bar)
                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                // mAudioViewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(mConvertView.VISIBLE);
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                                String yofile = "file://" + filepath;
                                mediaPlayer
                                        .setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                try {

                                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(yofile);

                                } catch (IllegalArgumentException
                                        | SecurityException
                                        | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    Log.e("Node", "ERRORSS Part 1 is" + e);

                                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                                @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 


                                                {
                                                    mAudioViewHolder.isPlaying = false;

                                                    /**
                                                     * since audio is stop
                                                     * playing, remove its
                                                     * position value
                                                     * */
                                                    playingAudioPosition = -1;
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                                try {
                                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("Node", "ERRORSS is Part 2 " + e);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                isMediaReleased = false;
                                mAudioViewHolder.progressBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                                updateSeekBar();

                            }

                        }



                    });


            mAudioViewHolder.pause
                    .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mAudioViewHolder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mAudioViewHolder.pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mediaPlayer.stop();

                        }
                    });


        }

     if (chatMessage.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("image") || chatMessage.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("photo")) 
     {
         mImageViewHolder = getImageViewHolder(mConvertView);
         mImageViewHolder.mChatmessage=chatMessage;
         Log.d("Node", "this is Image position is "+chatMessages.get(position));

        // TODO change below code
        if(chatMessage.getSenderId() != null)
            setAlignment(mImageViewHolder, chatMessage.getSenderId().intValue() != ((SMBChatApp) context.getApplication()).getQbUser().getId().intValue());
        else
            setAlignment(mImageViewHolder, false);

            mImageViewHolder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage.getDate_sent()));

            if (chatMessage.getProperty("localfile") != null) {

                imageUri1 = chatMessage.getProperty("localfile");
                String status = chatMessage.getProperty("isUpload");

                imageUri2 = "file://" + imageUri1;

                Log.d("Node", "This time from local");

                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(chatMessage.getUrl(),
                        mImageViewHolder.myimageview, disply);

                //
                // Log.d("Node", "IMAGEURI is : " + imageUri2
                // + "And  status is " + status);

            } else {

                Log.d("Node", "Here we are now else");
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(chatMessage.getUrl(),
                        mImageViewHolder.myimageview, disply);
            }

            mImageViewHolder.myimageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(context, "This is Image",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                            ShowImgActivity.class);

                    String urll = chatMessage.getUrl();

                    Bitmap bitmap = mImageViewHolder.myimageview.getDrawingCache();
                    intent.putExtra("URL", urll);

                    intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }


        //if aatchmnet is video then do this 
        else if (chatMessage.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {



            mImageViewHolder = getImageViewHolder(mConvertView);
            mImageViewHolder.mChatmessage=chatMessage;

            // TODO change below code
            if(chatMessage.getSenderId() != null)
                setAlignment(mImageViewHolder, chatMessage.getSenderId().intValue() != ((SMBChatApp) context.getApplication()).getQbUser().getId().intValue());
            else
                setAlignment(mImageViewHolder, false);

            mImageViewHolder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage.getDate_sent()));

            // Log.d("Node1", "This time from local videos");
            if (chatMessage.getVideo_thumb() != null) {

                Log.i("Node", "Yes this video has thumbnail");
                Bitmap bitmp = StringToBitMap(chatMessage.getProperty("video_thumb"));
                if (bitmp != null) {
                    mImageViewHolder.myimageview.setImageBitmap(bitmp);
                } else {
                    mImageViewHolder.myimageview
                    .setImageResource(R.drawable.vids);
                }

            } else {
                Log.i("Node", "Yes this dont have thumbanil");
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(chatMessage.getUrl(),
                        mImageViewHolder.myimageview, disply);
            }

            mImageViewHolder.myimageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final ImageView imageThumbnail =  (ImageView)v;

                    final Handler handler=new Handler() {
                        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                            Log.e("", "handeler bmVideoThumbnail"+bmVideoThumbnail);

                            if (bmVideoThumbnail!=null) {
                                imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmVideoThumbnail);
                            }

                        };
                    };

                    new Thread()
                    {
                        public void run() {
                            //We are creating  folder first using mkdir 
                            File f =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/smbchat/");                         
                            if(!f.exists()){
                                f.mkdirs();
                            }

                            //then we want to store downloded file in that folder 
                            File output =  new File(f, "VID_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "_video.mp4");

                            Log.d("Node", "URL VALUE "+chatMessage.getUrl());
                            HttpRequest.get(chatMessage.getUrl()).receive(output);

                            audioFileName=String.valueOf(output);



                            Log.d("Node", "FILE SAVED SUCCESSFULLY AUDIOFILENAME " + audioFileName);

                            donloadedVideoUri= "file://" + audioFileName;

                            Log.e("Node", "donloadedVideoUri INSIDE THREAD------"+donloadedVideoUri);

                            bmVideoThumbnail=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(audioFileName, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);       

                            Log.e("Node",      "bmVideoThumbnail---------"+bmVideoThumbnail);
                            if(bmVideoThumbnail !=null)
                                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


                            };

                    }.start();























//                  String uriString = chatMessage.getUrl();
//                  Uri intentUri = Uri.parse(uriString);
//
//                  Intent intent2 = new Intent();
//                  intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                  intent2.setDataAndType(intentUri, "video/*");
//                  context.startActivity(intent2);
                }
            });





     }




 }






        else {

                mTextViewHolder = getTextViewHolder(mConvertView);
                mTextViewHolder.mChatmessage=chatMessage;

                 Log.d("Node", "this is text position is "+chatMessages.get(position));
            //TODO redo following logic
            if(chatMessage.getSenderId() != null)
                setAlignment(mTextViewHolder, chatMessage.getSenderId().intValue() != ((SMBChatApp) context.getApplication()).getQbUser().getId().intValue());
            else
                setAlignment(mTextViewHolder, false);

            mTextViewHolder.txtInfo.setText(getTimeText(chatMessage.getDate_sent()));

            mTextViewHolder.txtMessage.setText(chatMessage.getBody());

            mTextViewHolder.message = chatMessage;


        }

    return mConvertView;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one ViewHolder and define three fields and show hide views according status.
Maintain Status in list not in adapter.
Because list item recreated on list view scroll.

Comment: how can I maintain status of Item whether thumbnail is downloaed or not

Comment: Create a enum and define different fields(START,ERROR,DOWNLOADED,COMPLETE). and show hide item according this enum values..

Answer (score 0):

You can see same thumbnail in multiple list items as Android reuses the view of list item.
Care needs to be taken that you make the thumbnail invisible or use 'Icon which suggests no image' if you don't have the correct image for that position of list item. This check has to be made in getView method of your adapter of the list.